# Add an amperand into set-body in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to use the `set-body` function and enter an `&` into the XML to add a parameter to a URL dynamically in a `liquid template`

For example

```
{% if {body.pagination} %}
  "url": "/api/device/select?stats=true&{{body.pagination}}",
{% else %}
  "url": "/api/device/select?stats=true",
{% endif %}
```

I receive the following error when trying to save the above

```
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 31, position 114.
```

Is there a way to escape the `&` symbol, I can't use `&amp;` as this is not recognised on the backend system

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `%26` for Url Encoding / Decoding:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent_character

For the correct output `%26`, has to be decoded by using the [liquid filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#supported-liquid-filters).-

```
{% if {body.pagination} %}
  "url": "{{"/api/device/select?stats=true%26" | UrlDecode}}{{body.pagination}}",
{% else %}
  "url": "/api/device/select?stats=true",
{% endif %}
```